# Using SQLite Query method with Special Case Order

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have a `query` method that currently looks like this:

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.MY_TABLE, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
```

What I want to do is add an `ORDER BY`.  But it's a bit complicated then a regular ORDER BY.  So in the last parameter I want an order that says

`my_order ASC WHEN my_order IS NOT '0'`

I am not sure if this is the proper syatax of if I need a `CASE` or what.

I basically want it to order the `my_order` field by 1,2,3, etc, then anything that is zero comes last in no particular order.  The `my_order` column is an `INT`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort zeros to the end, replace them with a value that compares larger than any number, such as a string:

```sql
SELECT ...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN my_order <> 0 THEN my_order ELSE '' END;
```

When your column contains strings, you have to construct some appropiate 'large' string.